# Deleting event asp.net; how to check if post was deleted or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, events

Using the ListView, I want to control if a DB post was deleted or not so I can display a message for the user. If I add a ..deleting event method to the code behind file, how could I check this?

Showing the "OK" message is easy, using the 'deleted' event, but I wanna be able to show the  "Not OK" message if the operation failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for the ItemDeleted event:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdeleted.aspx

Check out the Exception and ExceptionHandled properties of ListViewDeletedEventArgs.